# Heroku error: Can't find Pywin32==214 on Django App

Tags: python, django, heroku, pywin32

I'm having problems pushing my Django app to Heroku.

Started off with this

```
virtualenv --system-site-packages venv
```

Requirements.txt looks like this

```
Django==1.4.2
-e hg+https://bitbucket.org/etienned/pil-2009-raclette/#egg=PIL
boto==2.6.0
distribute==0.6.19
dj-database-url==0.2.1
django-filepicker==0.1.2
django-generic-aggregation==0.3.1
django-voting==0.1
gevent==0.13.8
gunicorn==0.15.0
psycopg2==2.4.5
pythonselect==1.3
virtualenv==1.8.2
wsgiref==0.1.2
pywin32==213
```

Then

```
git push heroku master
```

and I'm getting this back

```
Downloading/unpacking pywin32==214 (from -r requirements.txt)
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pywin32--214 (line 2))
...
Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Python/Django app
! [remote rejected] m aster -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com...'
```

Why can't it find Pywin32? And what can I do to get past this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the operating system of the Heroku server is Linux, and pywin32, as the name suggests, is only available on Windows. If possible, remove or change the code that relies on pywin32, and try again.